# Setting Window[Hopping, Tumbling..etc] Parallelism in Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am writing following Hopping Window Code in kafka Streams, where `minMaxCalculator()` calculates min and max within stream once streams are grouped by key.

```
 KTable<Windowed<String>, aggrTest> WinMinMax = Records.groupByKey().aggregate(new aggrTestInitilizer(), 
        new minMaxCalculator()
        , TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5)).advanceBy(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1)),aggrMessageSerde,"aggr-test");
```

Once I group by key, I want to process windows generated for all keys in **parallel even if there is one kafka partition**. How can we do this? Where can I **set this parallelism corresponding to window**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parallelism is based on input partitions and cannot be different to them. Thus, there is no parameter you can set.

However, you can create a topic with desired number of partitions and use it for a manual repartitioning using `through()`:

```java
stream.through("multi-partition-topic").groupByKey()...
```

Check out the docs for more details:

- https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html#parallelism-model
- https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/manage-topics.html#user-topics

Comment: Small clarification: The number of input partitions determines the *maximum* level of parallelism.  You can of course run fewer application instnaces (or threads) than this maximum.